# AVPlayerViewController (tvOS) doesn't pause on viewWillDisappear

Tags: tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I have several `AVPlayerViewControllers` set as the `ViewControllers` of a `UITabBarController`. What I want is having the video of the currently visible `AVPlayerViewController` automatically pause playing when the user switches to another tab (which is another `AVPlayerViewController`)

I tried this approach:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    player?.pause()

    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

but the video just keeps running in the background. (audio is still running at least) Debugger says player property is not nil in viewWillDisappear. I already tried implicitly and forced unwrapping, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to identify the problem. It seems to be that you can't pause in `viewWillDisappear`, neither with `pause()` nor with `player?.rate = 0.0`. So in order to prevent your video from playing in the background, you have to set `AVPlayerViewController`'s `player` property to nil in `viewWillDisappear`. 
Which sadly means that you have to write some code for preserving your playback state.

Seems a bit like a bug to me, hope this will get fixed later.

Comment: This is the answer I am looking after.